# Electron IPC: Why is my ipc message not being received?

Tags: ipc, electron

My main process (important code):

```
let introWindow
let win = null

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    introWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 600,
            height: 480,
            title: "Glaze",
            resizable: false
        })
        // and load the index.html of the app.


    introWindow.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'src/html/start.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }))

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    introWindow.on('closed', function() {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        introWindow = null
    })
}

function createMainWindow(arg) {
    const htmlPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'src/html/index.html?room=' + arg.room + "&nick=" + arg.nick)
    win = new BrowserWindow({
           width: 800,
           height: 700,
           title: "Glaze"
       })
    win.on('closed', function () {
         win = null;
    })

   win.loadURL(htmlPath)
   win.show()

   win.webContents.send('message', "IT WORKED!");

   autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
     sendStatus('Checking for update...');
   })
   autoUpdater.on('update-available', (ev, info) => {
     sendStatus('Update available.');
   })
   autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (ev, info) => {
     sendStatus('Update not available.');
   })
   autoUpdater.on('error', (ev, err) => {
     sendStatus('Error in auto-updater.');
   })
   autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (ev, progressObj) => {
     sendStatus('Download progress...');
     log.info('progressObj', progressObj);
   })
   autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (ev, info) => {
     sendStatus('Update downloaded.  Will quit and install in 5 seconds.');
     // Wait 5 seconds, then quit and install
     setTimeout(function() {
       autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
     }, 5000)
   })
   // Wait a second for the window to exist before checking for updates.
   setTimeout(function() {
     autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()
 }, 5000);
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', function() {
        const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
        Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
        createWindow()

})

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    let reopenMenuItem = findReopenMenuItem()
    if (reopenMenuItem) reopenMenuItem.enabled = true
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', function() {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (introWindow === null && win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

app.on('browser-window-created', function() {
    let reopenMenuItem = findReopenMenuItem()
    if (reopenMenuItem) reopenMenuItem.enabled = false
})



ipc.on('close-starter', function(event, arg) {
    createMainWindow(arg);
})





function sendStatus(text) {
  log.info(text);
  win.webContents.send('message', text);
}
```

And my index.html:

```
    <script>
    const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
    ipc.on('message', function(event, text) {
        console.log("Message received")
        console.log(text, event);
        var container = document.getElementById('messages');
        var message = document.createElement('div');
        message.innerHTML = text;
        container.appendChild(message);
    })

    console.log("ran")
</script>
```

When I run my app, I check the dev tools console in my `win` window and there are no messages printed out except `ran` noting that the file ran. Why is the ipc message not getting through? `win` should not equal null at that point when the `.send` is called. Could the issue be with my main file or with my receiving file?

Comment: when I say the console, I mean the dev tools console. And yes I have already tried that @pergy

Comment: I see,  ofc. And if you send only `on('dom-ready')`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean calling `send` in `webContents.on('dom-ready')` only

Comment: YES! That solved it thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a summary of my comment, `ipc` channel can be used only after `webContents` are setup successfully. Therefore, you should place your `send` call in a callback which ensures that `ipc` channel is in service.

In [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-) of `send` example code is doing the same thing:

```
// In the main process.
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = null

app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.webContents.send('ping', 'whoooooooh!')
  })
})
```